# One SQL Server RDS instance plus one Ubuntu instance cost money on my initial free trial year

Tags: linux, amazon-rds, aws

Why do I get charged when I only have one micro instance running as Ubuntu and another one a RDS. Does the extra RDS count as a separate instance? My RDS is Microsoft SQL Server exchange which should be free.

I wonder if there is any place where I can get started with node and a database that isn't as annoying as aws. Their documentation is horrible. It feels like the medical system. I never know what will cost me until I get the bill and then it's always surprising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes technically both are considered separate instances.  However you get 750 hours free for each as they are billed as separate services with the caveat that instance sizes have to be a t2 micro.  Since RDS is a managed service you won’t see the running instance in your ec2 console even though it’s an instance running in your account.

Some things to look at on your bill as they might be the cause of the [charges](https://aws.amazon.com/free/faqs/?ft=n):

- Are you using more than 30gb for EBS volumes attached to your ec2 instance (You can have any combination of gp2 or hdd EBS volumes, they just need to be <= 30gb)
- Did you allocate more than 20gb for your RDS instance
- [Have you been stopping and starting your ec2 instance multiple times an hour](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/) (Each time you stop then start your instance the clock starts over on the running costs. Restarts keep the clock running)
- Multiple snapshots of the EBS/RDS volumes

Comment: 20Gb on the RDS and 8 on the Ubuntu.
didn't restart them more than maybe a few times accidentally 
"750 hours of Amazon EC2 Linux t2.micro instance usage" 100% - 2,325 Hrs forcasted month end. I did have multiple instances for the first few days of the month, maybe that was it.
750 hours of Amazon RDS Single-AZ db.t2.micro Instances 38%. 
I guess I'll terminate my instances when I'm not actively developing/testing. I'm playing on my localhost currently. I don't have snapshots of the database.

Comment: The 2325 EC2 Linux t2.micro - This is where the cost is coming from. I wasn't sure if the RDS database counts. I guess one way of having this run non stop for free in the first year is to have a mysql database on the ubuntu instance so that wouldn't count extra. The sad thing I like sql server better because I know it from my full time job. Plus the Microsoft SQL Operations Studio on my linux looks so cool as opposed to the MySql Workbench. 

I wonder if I can use Microsoft Azure cloud to host the SQL Server database for free and the AWS instance to communicate with that DB.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/free/faqs/?ft=n this link you provided seems to imply one of each would be free for one month continuous usage but my bill seems to indicate otherwise. I don't get it. Maybe my reading comprehension skills are lacking.

Comment: @Dong you don’t have to terminate it to stop the clock. Simply stopping the instance is enough

Comment: The estimates in my experience will update every 24 based on what it has seen used. You can put in some simple billing alerts that will let you know if you are getting close to your monthly limit

Comment: @Dong perhaps the most common reason for this is that you've created the same thing in more than one region, but you only see one region at a time in the console.